# Python opencv running extraordinarily slow

Tags: python, opencv

Keep in mind I'm very new to coding and find this very difficult, but my open cv code is running super slow, and i have checked task manager and the cpu is running at less than ten percent of it's max usage, so it's not lack of processing power. Haar_face.xml is just opencv's haar cascade frontal face default. the slow thing is one, it starts up really slowly and two, it returns about one frame every five seconds, which is far too slow and i'm not sure why. any help appreciated.

```
 import cv2 as cv
 while True:
    wcapture = cv.VideoCapture(0)

    ret, frame = wcapture.read()

    imgGray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()


    face_haar = cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')

    faces_rect = face_haar.detectMultiScale(imgGray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3)

    print({len(faces_rect)})

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
        cv.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
    cv.imshow('Detected Faces', frame)



    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('d'):
        break
wcapture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please try putting some things out of the while loop. May you only need the for loop, and everything else can be outside. It is difficult to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: You're creating a new `cv.VideoCapture` instance in each iteration of the loop. Not sure how much of the execution time that accounts for, but should see an improvement if you move it out.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thanks frippe!

Comment: 8% on windows can be one complete CPU core of a 12-core system. please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have opencv installed on the machine I'm currently on, but moving the creation of the `cv.VideoCapture` out of the loop and not destroying all windows each time should speed up the execution:

```
import cv2 as cv
wcapture = cv.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = wcapture.read()
    if ret:
        imgGray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face_haar = cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')

        faces_rect = face_haar.detectMultiScale(imgGray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3)

        print({len(faces_rect)})

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
            cv.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.imshow('Detected Faces', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('d'):
        break
wcapture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```